# $watch is not working in Modal even though using like $scope.user={pwd1:''}

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-watch

Please refer my Plunker link :
http://plnkr.co/edit/0vOjw0?p=preview

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="angular.min.js?version=1.4.2"></script>
    <script src="ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>




  <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-right: 7px;float: left;">
      <button ng-controller="registrationCtrl" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" ng-click="openRegistration()"> Registration</button>
  </div>




  </body>

</html>
```

registration.html

```
<div class="modal-dialog" id="registration.html">


        <div class="modal-body">

            <form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>



                <label for="pw1">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="pw1" name="pw1" ng-model="user.pw1" ng-required="" />
                <div>{{user.pw1}}</div>


            </form>

        <div class="modal-footer">

            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap']).controller('registrationCtrl', ['$scope','$modal',function ($scope, $modal)
    {

        $scope.openRegistration = function ()
        {
            //console.log("inside openLogin");
            var modalInstance =$modal.open(
                {
                    templateUrl: 'registration.html',
                    controller: 'registrationPopupController',
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false,
                    size: 'sm'
                });
            //console.log("done open")
        }
    }]).controller('registrationPopupController', ['$location','$scope','$modalInstance',function ($location,$scope,$modalInstance,LoginService)
    {

        $scope.user={
            pwd1:''
        };
        $scope.$watch('user.pwd1',function(newV,oldV){
          if(newV!=oldV){
          alert(newV)
            console.log(newV,oldV);
          }

        },true);


        $scope.cancel = function ()
        {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            location.href='#/';
        };

    }]);
```

The problem i am facing is when write in password text box, my $watch will not invoke in modal instance controller. but then when i write in same simple controller it will work, please help me out!!

Comment: Not sure if this the case, but you are running $watch on something that is not a scope variable. `user` is a scope variable, user.pw1 isn't. It is an attribute of an object, which happens to be a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a typo in your `ng-model` value, it should be `user.pwd1` instead of `user.pw1`

**Markup**

```
<input type="password" id="pwd1" name="pw1" ng-model="user.pw1" ng-required="" />
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/L5KhRb?p=preview)

Comment: @intellect_dp could you upvote please. Glad to help you with that :)